# Filtering a dataframe after groupBy and user-define-aggregate-function in Pyspark will cause java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I found some strange error when I'm coding Pyspark UDAF. After I call groupBy function and agg function, I want to filter some data from remaining dataframe, but it seems not work. My sample code is below.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType, col
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...     [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
...     ("id", "v"))
>>> @pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
... def mean_udf(v):
...     return v.mean()
>>> df.groupby("id").agg(mean_udf(df['v']).alias("mean")).filter(col("mean") > 5).show()
```

The code above will cause exception printed below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 378, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3717.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1726L, 200)
+- *(1) Filter (mean_udf(v#1727) > 5.0)
   +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#1726L,v#1727]

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:391)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.AggregateInPandasExec.doExecute(AggregateInPandasExec.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: mean_udf(input[1, double, true])
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable$class.doGenCode(Expression.scala:261)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.PythonUDF.doGenCode(PythonUDF.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:105)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.genCode(Expression.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.nullSafeCodeGen(Expression.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.defineCodeGen(Expression.scala:508)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryComparison.doGenCode(predicates.scala:563)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:105)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.genCode(Expression.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$FilterExec$$genPredicate$1(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec$$anonfun$13.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec$$anonfun$13.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:163)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:544)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:598)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
        ... 48 more
```

Well, actually I found solution by using asNondeterministic function. Telling Catalyst Optimizer not optimize mean function, but this solution is not elegant for me.
Could someone tell me why this exception happens? It seems like Catalyst Optimizer try to call mean function in jvm, but why? Is there more elegant solution exist?

update:

I found several solutions to solve this problem.

1. use asNondeterministic function to avoid optimization

```
>>> mean_udf = mean_udf.asNondeterministic()
```

2. use pandas group map function instead
3. use cache

```
>>> df.groupby("id").agg(mean_udf(df['v']).alias("mean")).cache().filter(f.col("mean") > 5).show()
```

But, it's still a big problem when using pandas UDAF

Comment: Why do not you use `F.mean(F.col('v'))` instead of defining udf?

Comment: It's just an example to illustrate my problem. Actually, my UDAF is more complicated than this sample function, I just want to know why this exception happens

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably a bug for PySpark. As you found out, the optimizer tried to optimize the plan, but encountered some expression it can't evaluate, i.e. `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: mean_udf(input[1, double, true])`.

To fix the issue, one needs to stop the optimization right before the filter step. 
I found `df.cache()` works here.

```
df = df.groupby("id").agg(mean_udf(df['v']).alias("mean"))
df.cache()
df.filter(F.col("mean") > 5).show()
```

Comment: Well, if it is a bug, it's really a severe bug for PySpark, filtering data after pandas aggregation function is a frequent operation in python data analysis.